# Forcing Synchronous Behavior In Async Methods For Recursion

Tags: vb.net, recursion, async-await

I'm relatively new to the async/await pattern, but I'm trying to get up to speed because I'm using a 3rd party API that only exposes async methods. I need to write a recursive method to crawl through a directory structure. Suppose for example the structure looked like this:

```
/(root)
    Folder1/
        Folder3/
        Folder4/
    Folder2/
        Folder5/
            Folder6
```

My initial version of the crawl was a "fully" async version, and it looked something like this:

```
Async Function GetFolderContents(thisPath) As Task(Of Blah())
    Dim result as Blah()
    thisFolderContents = await _thirdPartyAsyncMethod.GetContents(thisPath)
    For Each singleFolder In thisFolderContents
         result.Add(singleFolder)
         result.AddRange(await GetFolderContents(singleFolder))
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Whenever I tried to call this method, I could never get any of the results of Folder2 or its children - I could only get it to return Folder1 and its children. Based on my tenuous knowledge of async/await I kind of understand why that would be (though I'm fully prepared to admit I just might be doing it wrong).

I could make it work the way I expected by removing Async from my method definition and using the .Result of the third party async method:

```
thisFolderContents = _thirdPartyAsyncMethod.GetContents(thisPath).Result
```

Even though this seems to work my question is, *should* I be doing it that way? I gather these methods were made async for a reason and this method effectively makes then synchronous. Is there a more proper way to implement recursion when calling async methods that you didn't write, or is this one of the edge cases where using .Result is the only way to do it?

Comment: What you're describing isn't possible. `await x` must have exactly the same results as `x.Result`. There must be some bug in code that isn't shown.

Comment: You're right. I was going about what I needed to do in a kind of funky way that was probably not appropriate for recursion. When I changed the approach I got the same result using Await and .Result.